# Error when tried to use self.presentingViewController!.presentViewController after dismissViewController by Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i always got an error like this

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

after i used

```
self.presentingViewController!.presentViewController
```

inside the completion of

```
dismissViewControllerAnimated function
```

this is my code.

// BeatBiddingModalViewController

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: { () -> Void in

        let navigation: UINavigationController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("dealInSideView") as! UINavigationController            
        let vc1: DealInsideViewController = navigation.topViewController as! DealInsideViewController

        vc1.dealId = self.dealId

        self.presentingViewController!.presentViewController(navigation, animated: true, completion: {})
        //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

    })
```

How can i fix This? 
Thanks!

// appDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    let navigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("beatingDealView") as! UINavigationController
    let bealBiddingVc: BeatBiddingModalViewController = navigationController.topViewController as! BeatBiddingModalViewController

    bealBiddingVc.dealId = tempDealId
    bealBiddingVc.beatBiddingText = tempDealText
    bealBiddingVc.dealName = tempDealName
    self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(navigationController, animated: true, completion: {})
}
```

** add some details
This view was presented by appDelegate.swift not just normal view.

My app concept is receiving Remote from the server then presentView for user to take some action. And one off them is about dismiss this modal presentView then present the other with some value from notification.

Comment: because you are using dispatch_async, there is a very good chance that the viewController hierarchy has already been dismantled by the time the code is executed, thus, there may not be a reference to the presentingViewController at this time. Though I'm not positive about this. Have you considered using a delegate method in which the presented viewController could tell the presentingViewController to dismiss the presented viewController and subsequently present a new one? 

Just a thought.

Comment: i have tried the code without  dispatch_async before but also got the same error and i can't use delegate because this current was presented from appDelegate .swift

Comment: Oh! So this viewController was set as the rootViewController? In which case, it does not have a presentingViewController? If that's the case, you should call a method in AppDelegate.swift that would set `self.window.rootViewController = navigation`, I could write up an answer for you, if that was the case.

Comment: already add my code on appDelegate.swift on the question.
Thanks!